# Convert Array To a Specific Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way to convert this array :

```
array=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

to

```
$scope.editcity = {
      cities : [
        {id: 1, name: "a", selected: false},
        {id: 2, name: "b", selected: false},
        {id: 3, name: "c", selected: false},
        {id: 4, name: "d", selected: false}
]}
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: What do you mean by convert? Go straight from `array` to `$scope.editcity` or did you want to use the array to lookup the right `city`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just asking how to solve the problem? What's your solution to the problem? Why do you feel it is bad? Why do you search for the best one? By which metric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

var $scope = {} // just for this test - you wont need this line
$scope.editcity = {
      cities : array.map(function(c,i){
        return {
            id: i+1,
            name: c,
            selected:false
          }
      })
};

console.log($scope.editcity)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

$scope.editcity = {
  cities : array.map(function(v, i){
    return  {
       id : i + 1,
       name : v,
       selected : false
    }
  })
}
```

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

var editcity = {
  cities: array.map(function(v, i) {
    return {
      id: i + 1,
      name: v,
      selected: false
    }
  })
}

console.log(editcity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method to return object.

```js
var array=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

var editcity = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  r.city = (r.city || []).concat({id: i + 1, name: e, selected: false})
  return r
}, {})

console.log(editcity)
```